# Disable Consul for integration tests with SB 2.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

Since new SB configuration property `spring.config.import` in `SB 2.4`, I cannot get integration tests working. Previously, I had `bootstrap-test.yml` with `spring.cloud.consul.enabled: false` and it worked nicely. Since upgrade to `2.4.3`, I have `spring.config.import: "consul:"` in `application yml`, and nothing seems to disable it in application-test.yml file. I have tried every possible combination of overriding `spring.config.import: "optional:consul:"` and setting `spring.cloud.consul.enabled: false` in `application-test.yml`. Yet I am still getting the same error

```
Config data resource ... via location 'consul:' does not exist
```

I don´t want to use optional import in application.yml, since main should not start without it. Only thing that seemed to help was setting `use-legacy-processing: true` but I don´t understand why.

Comment: Setting `spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false` should work. Can you share your configuration? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulConfigDataLocationResolver.java#L75 I wonder if trying to set it in a profile is too late. Can you try to set it in `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: Sure, when I set it on `@SpringBootTest`, given `spring.config.import=consul:` I get `Unable to load config data from 'consul:', File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/'`

Comment: ok, thanks for the information. Likely a bug

Comment: The more I think about it, I don't there is a bug. `spring.config.import` can't be overridden in an application-<profile>.yml file since it is additive (it's a special property). Not sure how to cover your situation yet, going to chat with a spring boot engineer.

Comment: Do you have other profiles for other environments?

Comment: After chatting with a boot engineer, we're going to make a behavior change so that the `'consul:', File extension is not known` error goes away.

Comment: Hmm, that would require a change in spring boot, or an empty property source. So my question about profiles still stands.

Comment: Only `-local` for obvious purposes, but I have consul running for local development so I only need to disable it for integration tests.

Comment: I don´t want to bother you, but did you have in mind some specific fix / workaround I can use? @spencergibb

Comment: There will likely be a fix. Still deciding if it should go in boot or spring cloud. As far as workarounds go, maybe adjusting where spring.config.imports actually take place. Maybe not in application.yml just in a profile specific one?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely just a workaround according to the comments on the question but it works for me for the moment. Your milage may vary.

Specifying the spring.config.import property as an environment variable allowed it to not be set for the tests but to work for the point where the application was deployed.

My full setup.

- `application.yml` contains normal consul enabled config.
- `application-standalone.yml` just disables all properties except `spring.config.import`
- spring.config.import is only added to the launch parameters.